# AngularJS: Routing with URL having optional parameters

Tags: angularjs, parameters, router, option-type

I have a URL in my app.js containing routes. lets say the url is:

```
/api/:opt1/:opt2/:opt3/users
```

I want that my url will work in any case, i should able to ignore the optional parameters (opt1, opt2 or opt3, may be all or few). How can I achieve this.

Is there any way that I can call `$location.path('/users')`, and I can specify also what are the values of the optional parameters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Optional route parameters are marked with `?`, like this:

```
`/users/:id?`
```

Then this route matches both `/users` and `/users/1` paths

Comment: With Angular 1.3.4 I'm getting this error when I try that: `Error: Invalid parameter name '' in pattern '/users/:id?'`

Comment: Not working for me...Do i need some module/library?.. I am using ui-router? I also tried adding ngRoute but still no result

Comment: @Sami this is not for ui-router. In ui-router you shall use query string `/users?id`